# handle run-time panic gracefully in go

Tags: go, signals

my application uses a logging pipeline, so requirement is to handle runtime panic gracefully like sednding a message on logging pipeline to declare the app going down, so that rule engine can work on it.

having said the goal, i followed go doc for signal (https://golang.org/src/os/signal/doc.go) it mentions about SIGBUS, SIGFPE, and SIGSEGV but not clearly mention about how to catch them in code. So i tried with go test and signal handler in app but it does not get called. Is there  a way to achieve the goal.

```
func sigHandler1(exitChannel, syncChannel chan bool) {
 c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
 signal.Notify(c)

 go func() {
    for {
        // Block until a signal is received.
        s := <-c
        mlog.Info(" got signal1: %+v", s)
        switch s {
        // kill -SIGHUP XXXX
        case syscall.SIGHUP, syscall.SIGQUIT,syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM:
            exitChannel <- true
        case syscall.SIGSEGV:
            syncChannel <-true   
        default:
            log.Println("Unknown signal.")
        }
    }
}()
```

}

```
func Test() {
    var msgBuf []byte

    log.Println("Test going to generate panic")
    msgBuf[0] = 1

}
```

panic result are as follows.

```
 panic: runtime error: index out of range [recovered]
 panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 10 [running]:
panic(0x515de0, 0xc420010150)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.5/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
testing.tRunner.func1(0xc420092300)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.5/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:579 +0x25d
panic(0x515de0, 0xc420010150)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.5/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:458 +0x243
app.Test()
    app/main.go:142 +0x56
app.TestMHProcessDlAck_22(0xc420092300)
    app.mh_test.go:946 +0x68
testing.tRunner(0xc420092300, 0x60bc90)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.5/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:610 +0x81
created by testing.(*T).Run
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.5/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:646 +0x2ec
exit status 2
FAIL    app 0.085s
```

Comment: You use `recover` to recover from a `panic`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: recover is only used when there is a panic inside a goroutine, where as in my case app is long running message driven app and if there is a runtime panic we want to emit a message on logging pipeline to declare it is going down. Also i tried adding a defer function calling recover in my main function but that didnt help either.

Comment: You can't globally catch panics, they are intended to crash the program as the program may be in an undefined state. A panic isn't a signal, so you can't catch it with a signal handler either if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: yes i was thinking of trying to catch via signal handler. And my requirement is to emit a message on stderr before exiting, so state of the program does not matter much.

Comment: if you need to be notified of the program crashing in all cases, you need to monitor the application from another process. You could try something like https://github.com/mitchellh/panicwrap

Comment: Thanks Jim. That helps.